# Google Tag Manager tracking 404 page without unique URL

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to find a way to use Google tag manager to fire a tag only when a 404 page is reached. The problem is that the 404 pages do not have "404" in the URL because there is no redirect.

For instance, if you entered:

www.example.com/ofiwefoign

This is not a page on the website, and you see the 404 page telling you that the page could not be found. However, you aren't seeing www.example.com/404.

Since the URL could be anything, I need another way to get the tag to fire. I apologize if this question seems silly, but I'm having a hard time figuring it out.

I was wondering if I could possible track by H1 or title tag, which would include "404"

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can grab content from the page. Here is an example (looking at `document.title`):

Click on the tag to go to the **Edit Tag** screen.

On the right, under **Firing Rules** click on the **+ Add** button.

Select **Create new rule**.

For **Rule Name**, name your rule something like "404 Page".

Under **Conditions** select "New macro..".

For **Macro Name** name the macro something like "404 title tag".

For **Macro Type** select "Custom Javascript".

In the **Custom Javascript** textarea, enter the following:

```
function () {
  return (document.title.indexOf('404')!=-1)?'true':'false';
}
```

This will return a string value of "true" if the title tag contains "404", or "false" if not. You didn't specify what your title tag actually looks like, so you may need to adjust this to fit what you expect your title tag to contain.

Click **Save** to save the macro details, and you should now see `{{404 title tag}}` in the dropdown back on the previous screen where you are creating the rule.

Set the operator dropdown to `equals` and in the text field to the right, enter in "true" (no quotes).

Click **Save** to save the rule.

Click **Save** at the bottom of the **Edit Tag** page to save the tag settings.

On the top-right of the tag overview page, click **Publish** to publish the changes, and you should be good to go.

Comment: Fantastic. I had been trying something similar, but there were a few issues in the syntax (new to JS). I tried out your suggestion and I've now got the tag firing as it should. I appreciate the help.

Comment: @user3470247 great! if you could mark this as solved then that would be awesome :)